# Why do I have to type the greater than symbol (>) in the VS Code command palette to access commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why do I have to type the greater than symbol (>) in the VS Code command palette to access commands?

It seems like work for no reason. Maybe I am missing something?

Is there a way to change some default somewhere so that I can just start typing commands after I open the palette?

Comment: How are you opening the command palette? Because if you really did open the command palette, it already has the `>` and you can immediately enter commands. I think what you are opening instead is the fuzzy file finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the palette holding the right shift key (Shift + Cmd/Ctrl + P) and it will open already in the "command" mode instead of the file search mode.